# Bukkit updating the name of an item every tick of the game

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to update the remaining seconds every tick of the game. I dont know here to start

This is my code atm:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
public void ItemRightClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    Action a = e.getAction();
    ItemStack item = p.getItemInHand();
    ItemMeta itemmeta = item.getItemMeta();



    if(a == Action.PHYSICAL) return;
    if(!p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.DIAMOND_HOE)) return;
    if(!itemmeta.getDisplayName().contains("Wand of Regen")) return;
    if(cooldown.containsKey(p)) {
        if(cooldown.get(p) + cooldownTime <= System.currentTimeMillis()) { 
            cooldown.remove(p);
            } else {
                if((int) (cooldown.get(p) + cooldownTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000 != 0) {
                itemmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Wand of Regen" + ChatColor.GRAY + " - " + ChatColor.AQUA + "Remaining " + ChatColor.GREEN + (int) (cooldown.get(p) + cooldownTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000 + ChatColor.AQUA + " seconds");
                item.setItemMeta(itemmeta);
                return;
                }
                itemmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Wand of Regen" + ChatColor.GRAY + " - " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Ready");
                item.setItemMeta(itemmeta);
            }
        }

    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 5 * 100, 3));
    p.sendMessage("Regen activated");
    cooldown.put(p, System.currentTimeMillis());

}
```

How can I do it? They said use a scheduler but I am new at both java and bukkit so go easy on me.

Comment: If you're updating the number of remaining seconds, wouldn't you want to update the text every 20 ticks?

Comment: Yeah but how can I?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: [Bukkit Scheduler](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming#BukkitScheduler)?

Comment: I did but how can I get the exact player? I dont have a choice to e.getPlayer should I loop through all of the players?

Comment: Make a non-abstract class for the Runnable which is passed into the Scheduler. When you initialize the Runnable object you can pass in the player parameter. You would activate the scheduler inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin class add this:

```
private static Main instance;

public static Main getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;
}
```

Then start a Bukkit Scheduler with:

```
new BukkitRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to execute every tick
    }
}.runTaskTimer(Main.getInstance(), 1, 1);
```

Comment: `private static Main instance` should be terminated with a `;` (for some reason single-character edits are not allowed or I would have just fixed it)